# Errors in the high-level relational engine (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, cube

I made changes to a SQL Server table and when processing my cube I get these errors:

> Errors in the high-level relational engine. A connection could not be made to the data source with the DataSourceID of 'Channel Final', Name of 'Channel Final'

My question is: if I change column names of a table, how can I change the names of that table in the cube so that I don't get that error?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

this problem arises from improper connection error so, the solution is

1. Goto Data Source Designer
2. Impersonation Information
3. User name => Give your Window(Account User)
4. Password => Give your window(Account Password)

Answer (score 0):

First try update your dsv then remove column from affected dimension and add a new one with updated name. After that full process your dimension and cube in these steps.